# Deleting a number in EditText with button click

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I am making a calculator with a delete button. I want the delete button to delete one element at a time.

Example, when I press DEL btn, the no.3 will be removed from the EditText.

[image]

This is my code for the dlt btn

```
        if (txtResult.length() > 0){
            txtResult = txtResult.getText().Remove(txtResult.length() - 1);
            if (txtResult.equals("")){
                txtResult.setText("0");
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the equivalent of .Remove from c# to android studio java?
Thank you.

Comment: i think. you are missing  else condition,  'txtResult.setText(txtResult);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the string with `substring`. 
Try this:

```java
String a = "AAA";
a = a.substring(0, a.length() - 1);
System.out.println(a); // result: AA
```

- java string document(you can find some information about substring): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html